# Python Agent how to track various counters/values evolution over time with ElasticAPM?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana, monitoring, elastic-apm

I'm really new to APM & Kibana, but ok with Python & ElasticSearch. Before I had Graphite and it was quite easy to do custom tracking.

I'm looking to track 3 simple custom metrics and their evolution over time.

1. CounterName and it's value. For example queue_size: 23 and send it by any of the workers. What happens when different workers send different values? (because of the time, the value might increase/decrease rapidly).

I do have 20 names of queues to track. Should I put all under a service_name or should I use labels?

Before I used:

```
self._graphite.gauge("service.queuesize", 3322)
```

No idea what to have here now:
....

2. Time spent within a method. I saw here it's possible to have a context manager.

Before I had:

```
with self._graphite.timer("service.action")
```

Will become

```
with elasticapm.capture_span('service.action')
```

3. Number of requests. (only count no other tracking)

Before I had

```
self._graphite.incr("service.incoming_requests")
```

Is this correct?

```
client.begin_transaction('processors')
client.end_transaction('processors')
...
```

THanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

1. You can add a couple of different types of [metadata](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/get-started/7.6/metadata.html) to your events in APM. Since it sounds like you want to be able to search/dashboard/aggregate over these counters, you probably want labels, using [`elasticapm.label()`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/python/current/api.html#api-label).
2. [`elasticapm.capture_span`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/python/current/api.html#api-capture-span) is indeed the correct tool here. Note that it can be used either as a function decorator, or as a context manager.
3. Transactions are indeed the best way to keep track of request volume. If you're using one of the [supported frameworks](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/python/current/set-up.html) these transactions will be created automatically, so you don't have to deal with keeping track of the `Client` object or starting the transactions yourself.